# algorithm for maintaining a stack in java

Tags: java, collections

How would you maintain a stack so that whenever you pop from the stack, you know the minimum element in the stack? The algorithm should have a constant complexity

Thanks in advance

Comment: Errmm, [What have you tried??](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: This sounds like an interview question. (In particular, it's an interview question I had when I was applying to join Google.) What have you tried? What's the background here?

Comment: Also, just to add to what @JonSkeet mentioned, apparently, a little bit of "Google"-ing gives you a lot of hint to solve this problem as well :)

Comment: push them to the stack in order, peek will give you the minimum element every time you pop

Comment: @pwned.. What if we don't push in order??

Comment: @RohitJain why wouldn't you push them in order ?

Comment: @pwned.. Because question didn't said that.. And if the question allowed to push in order, then there is nothing left in it..

Comment: @user1455802 You want the minimum element to be popped out or just want to know which is the minimum element after every PUSH/POP operations ?

Comment: @KaipaMSarma.. OP wants to know what is the minimum element after he pops each element, i.e., change in minimum element..

Comment: ok, i got the question right now. I have removed my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's what you need to do..

You need to maintain some `data structure` containing information of each element you insert regarding, what was the `minimum` and `second minimum` value at the time when you inserted that element..

So, you want to have information like this: -

**For each Element pushed ->**

- minimum value after insertion
- minimum value before insertion

This information will be needed when you `pop` that element from stack.. So, you would know that, whether you are `popping` minimum value or not.. If yes, then you can replace the current `minimum` value with the `minimum value` before pushing this element.. If not, then there will be no change in `minimum` value at that time..

**For E.g: -**

Suppose currently you have following element in stack: -

```
[3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4]
```

- And you push a **value 8**.. Then you have two values to maintain..
  (minimum value before 8 in pushed, i.e. 2, and miminum value after 8
  is inserted, i.e. 2): -

  ```
  min_value_before_push = min(stack)
  push 8
  min_value_after_push = min(stack)
  ```
- And if you push a **value 1**, then `minimum_before_insertion` is 2,
  and `minimum_after_insertion` is 1: -

  ```
  min_value_before_push = 2
  min_value_after_push = 1
  ```

Now your stack is :-

```
[1, 8, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4]
```

Now, if you **`pop`**, You will see that for **`value 1`**: -

```
    min_value_before_push = 2
    min_value_after_push = 1
```

So, popping will alter the minimum value, So, you change the current minimum value with the `minimum_value_before_push` of 1.. So, again your minimum is 2..

Your current stack becomes : -

```
[8, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4]
```

**Now, let's check whether this algorithm works for `duplicate` element : -**

Suppose you want to push a `value 2` again..

```
min_value_before_push = 2
min_value_after_push = 2
```

Then you go on and `pop`, you see that for `value 2`, `min_value_after_push` is 2, so this means popping it will alter the minimum value.. So you replace this value with `min_value_before_push`, which is also 2.. Which is what we wanted..

**NOTE**: - One Benefit of this Algorithm is that, you won't need to do much comparison.. Just a comparison with `current_minimum_value` while pushing.. And a comparison with `current_minimum_value` when you `pop`..

You can try to proceed to think what `data structure` can you have..

Comment: Are you popping out the minimum element here

Comment: @KaipaMSarma.. OP question doesn't say that we need to pop minimum element.. It says, we need to find what is the minimum element after I pop an element from the stack.. I thought that was quite clear from the question..

Comment: I like the O(1) insertion.  Clever stackploitation.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer:  null values prohibited (just like ArrayDeque), and not rigorously tested.*

```java
import java.util.ArrayDeque;

public class PessimisticStack<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    private class Entry {
        private Entry(T t, T minNow) {
            this.t = t;
            this.minNow = minNow;
        }
        private final T t;
        private final T minNow;
    }

    private final ArrayDeque<Entry> deque;

    public PessimisticStack() {
        deque = new ArrayDeque<Entry>();
    }

    public PessimisticStack(int initialCapacity) {
        deque = new ArrayDeque<Entry>(initialCapacity);
    }

    public void push(T t) {
        if (t == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        Entry entry = null; 
        if (deque.isEmpty()) {
            entry = new Entry(t, t);
        }
        else {
            T prevMinimum = deque.peek().minNow;
            T newMinimum = null;
            if (t.compareTo(prevMinimum) < 0) {
                newMinimum = t;
            }
            else {
                newMinimum = prevMinimum;
            }
            entry = new Entry(t, newMinimum);
        }
        deque.push(entry);
    }

    public T pop() {
        return deque.pop().t;
    }

    public T getMinimum() {
        Entry entry = deque.peek();
        return (entry == null ? null : entry.minNow);
    }
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
PessimisticStack<String> stack = new PessimisticStack<String>();

stack.push("Zebra");
stack.push("Elephant");
stack.push("Bryan");
stack.push("Adam");
stack.push("Calvin");

String calvin = stack.pop();

// "Adam"
System.err.println(stack.getMinimum());

stack.push("Aaron");

// "Aaron"
System.err.println(stack.getMinimum());

String aaron = stack.pop();

// "Adam"
System.err.println(stack.getMinimum());

String adam = stack.pop();

// "Bryan"
System.err.println(stack.getMinimum());
```

Comment: I did not sort the stack.  I maintain a separate sorted LinkedList.  The stack order is always preserved and does not affect the LinkedList ordering, which is based solely on Comparable behavior and not at all on push order... run the example :)

Comment: @Joe.. Yeah you are right.. Just saw that you are maintaining your stack containing instances of your `Inner` class `Entry`.. Thats something different.. +1..

Comment: @Rohit Your insertion has better time complexity and cleverly exploits the stack behavior, so I've updated my code accordingly (with one small difference, I don't track previous minimum; I get it from peeking at the head)

Comment: @Joe.. Thanks :).. And your code looks fine to me.. It's exactly how I wanted it to work.. And I like the implementation..

Answer (score 1):

Use another stack, say `minStack`, when push an element `val`, check whether `val < minStack.peek()`, if so, push `val` to `minStack` as well; when pop from the `stack`, check the value pop, say `pop_val`, do `minStack.pop()` if `pop_val == minStack.peek()`.

Now that we've a `minStack` that keeps all `local-min-element` at particular time points(until the time when the next push to minStack is made), we can easily figure out when to pop from minStack by just checking whether the stack's top is a `local-min-element`, which has been introduced above already.

However, the method will work properly only when all the elements are unique to each other, otherwise, it will be a little more difficult to do, hint, use a counter :).